# PHP / Codeigniter - magic_quotes_gpc error

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have just had my server upgraded to PHP 5.3.19.

I am using CodeIgniter for a few of my projects ... now every time i load a CI project im getting the following error

```
Directive 'magic_quotes_gpc' is deprecated in PHP 5.3 and greater
```

Im wondering if anyone can help me out rectifying this error.

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a `magic_quotes_gpc` directive in your `php.ini` file. It needs to be removed.

The [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php) states...

> magic_quotes_gpc | "1" | PHP_INI_PERDIR   | PHP_INI_ALL in PHP <= 4.2.3.
>   Removed in PHP 5.4.0.