# Error Message: Directive 'magic_quotes_gpc' is no longer available in PHP codeigniter 3

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter-3

I am using codeigniter 3 and I have turn off  'magic_quotes_gpc' from php.ini still getting error

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Core Error

Message: Directive 'magic_quotes_gpc' is no longer available in PHP

Filename: Unknown

Line Number: 0

Backtrace:
```

Please help

Comment: Besides turning it off, have you also tried removing the setting entirely? As also discussed [in this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14000950/php-codeigniter-magic-quotes-gpc-error).

Comment: i have change that setting it was worked fine and again same error so i have clear history but still giving error after 2/3 redirection and refresh hits

Comment: "Changing" the value and "removing/deleting" is not the same; have you effectively deleted the entire config line? If so, please post the full config for other to assist.

Comment: how should i attached my config  ?

Comment: Simply edit your original question with as much detail, like the config. Also, please take a look at these [tips on how to improve your chances of getting an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).